# Hudson builds failing - hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM cannot be cast to hudson.scm.SubversionSCM

Tags: mercurial, hudson

I am currently getting the following error when I run a build from Hudson:

ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.Mailer aborted due to exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM cannot be cast to hudson.scm.SubversionSCM

Our builds were working fine last Thursday and since Friday of last week they have been failing due to the above error.

I can run the build locally on machien and the build server through the console with no issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a bug report. You should open a JIRA at hudson-ci.org.

Comment: Ok will do, thanks. 
I posted on here is cause someone else was experiencing the same thing.

Comment: Did you change your Hudson setup recently?  Upgrade Hudson or any of the plugins?   Could you provide the versions for Hudson and all plugins currently in use?  Also provide versions in use last Thursday when everything was working.

Comment: Yes we upgraded Hudson and the Mercurial plugin in hopes that it would fix the issue. We are currently running version 1.341 of Hudson and am sorry but cannot remember the version we were running. As for the Mercurial plugin we are running 1.25 where before we were running 1.23.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fix by updating the mailer plugin in Hudson.